# Proving $\int\sin^n(x)\ dx = - {\sin^{n-1}(x)\cos(x)\over n}+{n-1\over n}\int\sin^{n-2}(x)\ dx$

Tags: integration

$$\int\sin^n(x)\ dx = - {\sin^{n-1}(x)\cos(x)\over n}+{n-1\over n}\int\sin^{n-2}(x)\ dx$$

I am got as far as:

$$\int\sin^n(x)\ dx = [-\cos(x)\sin^{n-1}(x)]+(n-1)\int\sin^{n-2} dx -(n-1) \int\sin^n(x)\ dx $$

what I am confused on is how to add  $(n-1)\int\sin^n(x)\ dx $ to the left of the $=$ sign

My professor showed that it should be
$$ n\int\sin^n(x)\ dx = [-\cos(x)\sin^{n-1}(x)]+(n-1)\int\sin^{n-2}\, dx $$

Why is $n$ by itself?  how did the $-1$ disappear, is there a $+1$ outside the integral if nothing is shown??

Comment: You get $n$ because you obtain on the l.h.s.  the coefficient $\;1+(n-1)$.

Answer (score 1):

You have:

$\int\sin^n(x)\ dx = [-{\cos(x)\sin^{n-1}(x)}]+(n-1)\int\sin^{n-2} dx -(n-1)\int\sin^n(x)\ dx$

Add $(n-1)\int\sin^n(x)\ dx$ to both sides

$n\int\sin^n(x)\ dx = [-{\cos(x)\sin^{n-1}(x)}]+(n-1)\int\sin^{n-2} dx$

and divide both sides by $n$

$\int\sin^n(x)\ dx = \frac 1n[-{\cos(x)\sin^{n-1}(x)}]+\frac {(n-1)}{n}\int\sin^{n-2} dx$